# Overloading `operator[]` to return `node*` but it's returning `node` instead

Tags: c++

I am creating a a trie to hold words in lowercase letters and I want to overload [] operator to return the pointer to node containing next character

```
struct node{
    node *next[27];    //26 pointers for each character from 'a'-'z' and 27th one for end of word.

    node *& operator[] (char c){
        if(ch>='a' && ch<='z') return *(next+(c-'a'));
        return *(next+26);    // *(next+26) equivalent to next[26] but since I'm overloading the operator []
    }
};
```

I also tried returning `next+26` but that causes `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'node*&' from an rvalue of type 'node**'`

Now when I check the types of following variables inside `main()`

```
    node *trie=new node;
    cout<<typeid(trie).name()<<" "
        <<typeid(trie['_']).name()<<" "
        <<typeid(trie['d']).name();
```

Actual output : `P4node 4node 4node`
Desired output : `P4node P4node P4node`

Been messing with it from a day now, Please point out the mistake.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(*trie)['_']`?

Comment: Remember that the variable `trie` is a *pointer*. When you do `trie['_']` it's the same as `*(trie + '_')` which treats `trie` as an *array* of `node` elements, and the index `'_'` will be way out of bounds leading to *undefined behavior* if the expression was used at run-time (which it thankfully isn't in the case you show).

Comment: @songyuanyao Wow thanks man, It was a silly mistake from my side

Comment: How can I close the question now, since I've got my mistake?

Comment: Especially since there are no answer, one option is to just delete, but since SO wants content, this is not preferable, unless you think your question is totally useless for anybody else. Another option would be for @Someprogrammerdude to write that comment as an answer for you to accept. Third option would be, that you answer your own question.

Comment: Re: `return *(next+26);` -- the comment is wrong. You can write `return next[26];` here; the overloaded `operator[]` belongs to `node`, and only applies to `node` objects, not to their contents.

Comment: Note that all those operations on `char` variables only work when the character codes for the characters `'a'..'z'` are contiguous and increasing. There are character sets for which this is not the case (EBCDIC being the usual suspect), and on a platform that uses them, that code won't work. It always works for the digits `'0'..'9'` because the C++ standard (C as well) requires it. There is no such requirement for letters.